# In a graphical file browser, what would be a way to search for files by application with which they are compatible?

Tags: nautilus, gui, search

In Nautilus, one can use the search function to search for parts of filenames, e.g. ".mkv" or ".jpg".

Let's say I have a media directory filled with image files and video files all of different formats. How can I search using a GUI file browser for files that are, say, video files (so .ogg, .mkv, .mp4 and so on) or files suited to being opened by default by a video player application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pcmanfm`, the gui file manager default in Lubuntu 18.04 and previous, has an option on the menu **View / Sort Files / By File Type** that provides this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion good there. I was looking for *search* results as opposed to sorting files. However, your `pcmanfm` suggestion lead me to an answer. In the file browser, the search function can be engaged using a wildcard `*` and then also a file type (MIME type). This results in search results for, say, all video files at all subdirectories that appear with a URL like the following: `search:///home/user/media?recursive=1&show_hidden=0&name=*&name_ci=1&mime_types=video/*`, which works. So thanks for the suggestion! It would be good to add that detail to your answer.